# How to set component properties for different routes?

Tags: angular

I have a top-nav component in my Angular App, in three of routes i have to show the cart in that component, till now i was using a service with BehaviourSubject and when i was navigating like in Products route i was setting it to true and then in my top-nav i was checking that if it's true i had to show the cart.

But now i have to find another approach, something inside top-nav component that detect if i'm in "products" route to show the cart else if i'm in "shop" route to hide it as i'm using reuse route and i'm unable to set BehaviourSubject on navigation back in "products"

Which would be the best way to do the following?

in constructor of top-nav i have the following:

```
cartService.isCartEnabled.subscribe((data) => (this.cart = data));
```

and then in html i'm checking if `cart` is `true` i'm showing the cart icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add attributes to your route, then a route Guard to set the attribute on navigation.

Here a [link to angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration) about configuring the route attributes

You add a data node with some attributes to the route you want to display the cart on:

```
...
  {
    path: 'with-cart',
    component: YourComponent,
    data: { displayCar: true }
  },
  {
    path: 'without-cart',
    component: YourComponent,
  },
...
```

using a resolver (more details in [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data)) you could read this data parameter and set it on the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CartResolverService implements Resolve<boolean> {
  constructor(private yourService: YourService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    this.yourService.setDisplayCart(route.data.displayCart)
    
    return of(route.data.displayCart === true);
  }
}
```

and reconfigure the routes again with this resolver:

```
  {
    path: 'with-cart',
    component: YourComponent,
    data: { displayCar: true },
    resolve: {
      cartResolver: CartResolverService,
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'without-cart',
    component: YourComponent,
    resolve: {
      cartResolver: CartResolverService,
    },
  },
```

And, your nav needs to be subscribed to this service, so it can action the changes.

Comment: That's an awesome solution but as top-nav is used in every route i'd need to add the `Resolver` to each route, will it be a good solution even to check route url in `NavigationEnd` of top-nav and if the url path is different from the one in which the cart should be enabled just to set it to disabled?

Comment: you can always do the reverse, a variable that would hide the cart (instead of showing it) and add the resolver where you want to hide it

Comment: then you can subscribe to the route changes from your main component and set the cart to visible on the event NavigationStart (https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart)

Comment: actually as in any other route i was yet setting isCartEnabled to false i had just to add the resolver to path where i needed it, thank you!